# Question about the axioms of equality, particularly about the axiom of substitution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic

What troubles me is the notion of equality and related axioms. I used to think that “x=y” means that “x and y are precisely the same thing”. But now it seems to me that the statement “x and y are the same object” is actually ***defined*** by the statement “x=y”,which seems more formal in mathematics. And the relation of equality, to a large extent, is just a matter of definition. We may define the relation of equality for a class of objects freely so long as the axioms of equality(reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity and the axiom of substitution) are all satisfied. Is that correct?

What troubles me most is the **axiom of substitution**, though. I know that
any operation on objects defined using previous well-defined operations on those objects is also well-defined. Sometimes I succeed in understanding this (For instance, subtraction on the real numbers is well-defined, because subtraction is defined in terms of previous well-defined operations, namely addition and negation), but other times, I fail to understand this. For instance, suppose that m and m’ are integers such that **m=m’**, and suppose that $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is a sequence of reals with starting index m,while $(x_n)_{n=m’}^\infty$ is a sequence of reals with starting index m’.Then here are some questions: 1. if $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to some $L∈\mathbb{R}$, does $(x_n)_{n=m’}^\infty$ converge to $L$? 2. does the equation $sup(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty=sup(x_n)_{n=m'}^\infty$ hold? 3. if $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, is $(x_n)_{n=m'}^\infty$ also a Cauchy sequence? ... ...

I know that these propositions are **super easy to prove**, but my question is, **do we actually need to prove them ?**(Think about the axiom of substitution for subtraction mentioned above.Though we can prove it step by step, we **don’t need to**)

Is it meaningful to think of these kinds of questions? (It seems I have been trapped by these questions.) I find that in most textbooks on analysis or algebra, the authors never talk about the axiom of substitution.

I'm not a native speaker of English, and I apologize for any possible misunderstanding caused by the language barrier.

P.S. Let me add a proof here. Suppose that $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, then let's prove that $(x_n)_{n=m'}^\infty$ is also a Cauchy sequence.
Since $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, we have $\forall ε＞0:\exists N≥m:\forall j,k≥N:|x_j -x_k |＜ε$. But we know that $m=m'$, then certainly we have $\forall ε＞0:\exists N≥m':\forall j,k≥N:|x_j -x_k |＜ε$, which means that $(x_n)_{n=m'}^\infty$ is Cauchy. The key to this question is the substitution property for $≤$，i.e., $(N≥m \land m=m')\to(N≥m')$.

Comment: IMO you are over-complicating things... We have a sequence $(x_n)$ and we have $m=m'$; is it true that $x_m=x_{m'}$? I think yes...

Comment: Depending on the context, equality may have many different meanings.  Some computer languages simultaneously adopt 'equality' operators with all sorts of meanings.  For example Lisp has "=", "eq", "eql" and a few others.  However, in logic the meaning of equality as is Tarski's definition of truth, is the most rigid possible: two things are equal iff they are the very same thing.

Comment: But how can we tell whether two things are the very same thing? For instance, are 1/3 and 2/6 the same thing?

Comment: Assume not: $\dfrac 1 3 \ne \dfrac 2 6$; then, by axioms for equality: $1 \times 6 \ne 2 \times 3$.

Comment: I have the same concern, but I have never heard of the "Axiom of Substitution". Could you give a reference for it please?